# IPv6 stateless autoconfiguration + DNS

Tags: ipv6

How do you use radvd on linux/Ubuntu to distribute IPv6 DNS server addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, you should use a "RDNSS definition" in [radvd.conf](http://linuxreviews.org/man/radvd.conf/). However, I do not know if any client actually uses that option to autoconfigure the DNS server addresses; using [DHCPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6) should be more reliable.

**Edit:** Newer versions of NetworkManager (used by most popular Linux distributions) are able to use the RDNSS to autoconfigure the IPv6 DNS server addresses.